# Inserir Dados Automático MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Boa Noite Amigos,

estou buscando uma forma de poder registrar um campo por Exemplo Upload que cada vez que cai um arquivo PDF dentro de uma pasta Scanner na hospedagem FTP ele registre no bando esse arquivo de extensão PDF,

isso é possível? alguém já desenvolveu algo assim?

Comment: Bom dia amigo, sua dúvida não é exatamente sobre mysql. Qual seria o sistema operacional? você tem root no máquina? qual linguagem de programação você tem disponível?

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando o PHP, você pode criar um script que se conecte com o servidor de FTP e faça a leitura dos arquivos. Aqui você tem um exemplo de conexão usando a função ftp_connect

```html
$servidor = 'endereco_do_servidor'; 
$usuario = 'usuario'; // Usuário
$senha = 'senha'; // Senha
$ftp = ftp_connect($servidor); // Retorno: true ou false
```

Neste tutorial você tem uma explicação passo a passo de como funciona:

http://blog.thiagobelem.net/conexao-via-ftp-com-o-php

Neste outro post do Stack Overflow você tem um exemplo mais completo, onde você pega o último arquivo e grava o seu nome no banco de dados:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800625/how-to-get-latest-modified-csv-file-values-from-ftp-server-and-insert-it-into-my

Perceba que estas soluções não são automáticas, ou seja, teria que executar manualmente o seu script PHP. Para executar um script de forma periódica, isso vai depender do sistema operacional do seu servidor. No Windows, você utiliza o Agendador de Tarefas, em ambientes Unix se utiliza o Cronjobs.